# PEBMSRMEE (all four)

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

Determine the two-part 14-letter answer by looking at these images below. Please try to figure out as much as possible before posting partials. Good luck!

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**HINT:**

> B, G, C, I, 1

Comment: Does 'two-part' mean two words? Or 2 layers? I am desperately trying to make a certain hunch I have work that I can't see anything else now :)

Comment: What I meant was that the 14-letter answer is of the form ____ ____

Comment: I think I've obtained a 14-letter two-word phrase using images 2-5, does that seem possible? I still don't see how the first image or title fit though.

Comment: @Hexomino It's def possible without the 1st image. But reading your comment makes me question if you're on the right track. I have my reasons, can't say more for now though. But if you do have figured out, 2-5, feel free to post a partial since I think that's sufficient enough for a partial. But again, that should've lead you to a specific 14-letter answer, without any ambiguities

Comment: @Prim3numbah Hmmm, I will hold off for a while because I might not be right, in that case. If it goes for too long without an answer, I may post what I have in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> **[ANNUS MIRABILIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annus_Mirabilis_papers)** ("miracle year") - the collective name for the four hugely influential papers that [Albert Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) published in the journal *Annalen der Physik* in 1905.
>
>  This is confirmed by the title PEBMSRMEE, which comprises the initials of the major themes of these four papers (and satisfies the notion of 'all four' of something):
>
>  **P**hotoelectric **E**ffect,
>  **B**rownian **M**otion,
>  **S**pecial **R**elativity,
>  **M**ass-**E**nergy **E**quivalence

The pictures/rebuses resolve as follows:

> 1. This is a rebus for **BRILLIANT**. To resolve it, we need to consider the height and width of each of the 9 bars in the histogram (differentiated by the bullet points on the left). To this end, we consider a thin horizontal line segment to have zero height, and a thin vertical line segment to have zero width. We then concatenate the values for height and width and convert numbers to letters via A1Z26.
>
>  Doing this, our 9 bars correspond to the concatenated number values 02, 18, 09, 12, 12, 09, 01, 14, 20. These translate via A1Z26 to **B**, **R**, **I**, **L**, **L**, **I**, **A**, **N** and **T**!
>
>  2. This is a rebus for **GERMAN**. Each of the three words can be partnered with a colour to make a well-known expression: **Black** Hole, **Red** Dragon, **Gold** Medal. These colours in three horizontal stripes make up the flag of **Germany** - remove the 'y' to get 'German' here...
>
>  3. This is a rebus for **CLERK**. It is *almost* 'Clark' as in Clark Kent, the alias of Superman. Except the third letter (indicated in red) must be altered. Thus 'Clark' becomes 'Clerk' - the only other 5-letter word of the pattern CL_RK.
>
>  4. This is the [American Sign Language](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/i/inout.htm) action for the word '**IN**'.
>
>  5. This is a rebus for **1905**. Pointing the hour hand of the clock to 210 degrees and the minute hand to 30 degrees around the circle (starting from midnight as the origin, as indicated in the clock diagram) the hands would be pointing to 7 hours and 5 minutes. Considering this as the time 7:05 (ignoring the fact that ordinarily the hour hand would be 1/12 of the way between the '7' and '8' at exactly 19:05), and needing the *evening* time equivalent, this yields 19:05.
>
>  Putting this all together we get **BRILLIANT GERMAN CLERK IN 1905**. Albert Einstein was a German clerk in a patent office in Bern at the time of writing these four papers, which were published in 1905. The use of their initials in the title is confirmation that the final answer should be their common 14-letter collective name, **ANNUS MIRABILIS**, rather than merely his own name, which also happens to be 14 letters long!

Comment: I'm quite glad I didn't post my "answer" now.

Comment: @hexomino Oh, I'm intrigued by what you had! Any ideas about the first one? I feel like it must be staring me in the face...!

Comment: It's a little embarassing, I may share it later. No ideas yet. Notice also how the name is also 14 letters split in two parts.

Comment: @hexomino Ha, okay :) Yes, at first (once the images started to resolve for me) I thought the answer was just going to be the name itself, but then I twigged what the title must mean.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, probably a mislead on OP's part. Good work on getting this!

Comment: rot13(Ubj qvq lbh genafyngr gur svany vzntr gb avargrra ubhef naq svir zvahgrf? Guvf jnf bar bs gur gjb uvagf gung V unir znantrq gb vagrecerg, ohg gjb uhaqerq gra naq guvegl qrterrf fubhyq or gjragl (rvtug b'pybpx) naq gra (zvahgrf), abg avargrra naq svir.)

Comment: @El_Vanja rot13(Lbh arrq gb fgneg sebz 00:00 nf orvat 0 qrterrf. Jvgu 360 qrterrf ba n pybpx snpr, gur tnc orgjrra rnpu bs gur 12 ahzoref vf 30 qrterrf - guhf 210 qrterrf nebhaq sebz zvqavtug vf 7*30. V guvax lbh'ir fgnegrq sebz 1 gurer...)

Comment: rot13(Nu, gung jnf gur nqqvgvbany cvrpr bs ybtvp V'ir orra zvffvat. V gerngrq vg yvxr n erthyne pvepyr, jvgu mreb qrterrf orvat ng guerr b'pybpx naq zbivat pbhagre-pybpxjvfr, nf cerfragrq va zngu. V unqa'g nccyvrq vg gb na npghny pybpx naq vgf angheny zbirzragf. Gunaxf sbe gur rkcynangvba!)

Comment: @El_Vanja Ah, I can see how you might do that... How strange that in this particular instance it produces the same answer as my suggested error above whilst involving a totally unrelated process! :)

Comment: Nicely found, Stiv. A quibble with the question: rot13(Gur ubhe unaq vf ng 212.5 qrterrf, abg 210.)

Comment: Great job Stiv! :) For the first image (which wasn't *really* necessary but as a..let's say, suitable adjective ;P) rot13(guvax va grezf bs jvqgu*yratgu (jvqgu orvat iregvpny fvmr naq yratgu ubevmbagny fvmr) naq gura genafyngr gb yrggref (N1M26))

Comment: @Prim3numbah Okay, I see what word it clues now. I'll try and explain that to wrap it up for completeness...

Comment: (gur qbgf ner whfg gurer gb frcrengr gur *avar* yrggref juvpu ner qrfpevorq ol gur erq svtherf va gur tevq. Fb sbe rknzcyr gur svefg ebj ercerfragf O=0k2 (jvqgu 0, yratgu 2), frpbaq ebj ercerfragf E=1k8 (jvqgu 1, yratgu 8) rgp rgp.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Yeah, I figured :) It's just how to persuade people that's really width '0'!

Comment: Yea, I thoguht about that. But isn't a line defined in such a way that it does not have any width? The good ol' - what's the area of a line..